# Using AngularJS in Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a existing project in Ruby on Rails.

What is the best way to use AngularJS in Ruby on Rails app?

I want to use AngularJs for only specified modules, not for create SPA. This is good way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have seen colleagues do in order to achieve this sort of integration with an existing rails app is:

- Include angular.js and relevant dependencies in the specific app pages that are to be 'angularized'
- Interpolate whatever data is needed to bootstrap the angular controller into the html template which contains the angular app. This might include data about the resource being operated on. I've seen this done by rendering a [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl%22RABL%22) template inside of a haml/erb template.
- Using that interpolated data, call whatever API methods you need to get additional data on the fly. This is usually just a matter of implementing json handlers for routes you've already created.

I can't say whether this is best practice, but its an easy way to get started fast.

Best of luck, angular is a very enjoyable tool to work with once you get used to it.